# Why is restriction necessary on an order-preserving function for it to be an isotone extension?

Tags: order-theory

> Order-complete chains have a very special property. Suppose that $X$ and $Y$ are chains and $X_0$ is a subset of $X,$ and that $f$ is an order-preserving function from $X_0$ to $Y\,.$ The problem is: Does there exist an isotone extension of $f$ whose domain is $X\,?$ Unless some restriction is made on $f,$ the answer is "no", for if $X$ is the set of all positive real numbers, $X_0$ is the subset  consisting of all the numbers which are less then one, $Y= X_0$ and $f$ is the identity map, then it is easy to see that there is no isotone function.
>
> (Assuming an extension $f^{-},$ what is $f^{-}(1)\,$?) But this example also indicates the nature of difficulty, for $X_0$ is a subset of $X$ which has an upper bound and $f[X_0]$ has no upper bound. If an isotone extension $f^-$ exists, then the image under $f^-$ of an upper bound for a set $A$ is surely an upper bound for $f[A]\,.$

The above excerpt is taken from *General Topology* by *Kelley*; here he discusses whether an isotone extension exists or not.

I didn't get the example.

Why, if $X_0 =\{x\in \mathbb R: x\lt 1\}$ and $Y= X_0,$ there is no isotone function?

How come $X_0$ has an upper bound and not $f[X_0]\,?$

What/Why is basically the "*restriction*" the author is talking about, necessary to be an isotone extension?

Comment: What do you mean by isotone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearly $X_0$ has an upper bound *in* $\Bbb R$, for example $1$. But in $X_0$ it has no upper bound, because that would correspond to a maximal element strictly below $1$ in the real numbers.

So how can we extend the identity function to remain monotone? It would have to map bounded sets to bounded sets, but it is impossible to bound $X_0$ *in* $X_0$, so you cannot map any upper bound of $X_0$ from $\Bbb R$ into $X_0$ by extending the identity function *and* preserving monotonicity.

Comment: Hi @Asaf, sorry for the late response. Firstly, thanks for the answer. Could you tell me what you meant by _that would correspond to a maximal element strictly below 1 in the real numbers_? I'm not getting that statement.

Comment: Suppose that $f(1)=x$, then by isotony, you have to have that it if $y<1$, then $f(y)\leq x$. However, there is some $y\in(x,1)$ and $f(y)=y$, which is impossible.

Comment: I think I comprehended the point: $f(1)= x\,.$ Now, $\forall y \lt 1,~~ f(y)\lt f(1) = x\,.$ But here $y\in (x,1)\implies f(y) = y \gt x\implies f(y)\gt f(1) $ which contradicts the ordering. Am I right @Asaf? Thanks.

Comment: Yes. That's the main idea. An upper bound (like $1$) has to go somewhere into $(0,1)$, but since $(0,1)$ is fixed in place, it cannot be moved to an upper bound of the image.

Comment: That's @Asaf for the clarification!